# serialVersionUID Exception

Tags: java, serializable, serialversionuid

I'm currently writing a project where I have a serializable class ClientRepository. The class don't specifies any serialVersionUID. 
When I try to run my program, I got following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: ClientRepository; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -477189107700903771, local class serialVersionUID = -3576242897222506440
```

So I added a default serialVersionUID (1L), but now I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: ClientRepository; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -477189107700903771, local class serialVersionUID = 1
```

How can I change the "stream classdesc serialVersionUID" to 1L, so it won't conflict?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to change the *data* - instead, if you're *certain* that your class is still compatible with the old version (and if only one version has data out in the wild), change your declared `serialVersionUID` to -477189107700903771L to match the value in the data. The value is arbitrary - it just has to match what's in the data.

Of course, if your class has changed in an *incompatible* way, you'll need to write some custom serialization code.

Personally I try to avoid native binary serialization like this for precisely these brittleness reasons. You might wish to look at alternatives such as [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the objects that were serialized into the repository before adding  `serialVersionUID = 1L` - they still have generated serialVersionUID that is different from `1L`. You should purge the repository.